# Facebook openActiveSessionWithReadPermission reach completion too fast with status fail

Tags: objective-c, xcode

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:
 ^(FBSession *session,
   FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
     [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
 }];
```

Well, after a while an alert show us saying that my application tries to access facebook and ask whether it's allowed or not.

However, that alert shows up AFTER completion handler is reached.

State is already FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed by that time.

What should I do? Works fine in simulator.

Actually scrumptious sample in face book also fail on my iPhone. But I have facebook apps installed and logged in.

Comment: you must have missed something. I am currently having the same issue, but I have other app working properly.. I'm trying to figure out what has been missing. Facebook Developer doesn't have comprehensive step-by-step integration list...

Comment: in my case, I missed [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url]; in - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation

Comment: Sharon, I am having the same issue as you, especially when the user has revoked permissions while the app is still open. What did you do to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook Login checklist:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}


- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // We need to properly handle activation of the application with regards to SSO
    //  (e.g., returning from iOS 6.0 authorization dialog or from fast app switching).
    [FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // if the app is going away, we close the session object; this is a good idea because
    // things may be hanging off the session, that need releasing (completion block, etc.) and
    // other components in the app may be awaiting close notification in order to do cleanup
    [FBSession.activeSession close];
}
```

In my sessionStateChanged: I am doing this

```
switch ( state ) {
    case FBSessionStateOpen:
        [[Facebook _instance] fbDialogLogin:session.accessToken expirationDate:session.expirationDate];
        break;
    case FBSessionStateClosed:
        [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
        break;
    case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"FBSessionStateUnknown: %d", state);
        break;
}
```

And dont forget to make sure that your FacebookAppID and BundleID is the same as the one you create in Facebook Developer Dashboard!